# Is it bad or unnescessary to have an instantiated javascript function look up its own name?

Tags: javascript

I have had several occasions to have a instantiated function know its own name.

The obvious solution would be to create the function so that you can pass it its own name when you create it and just store that:

```
instancename = new functionname('instancename')
```

...but I don't particularly like that, it seems clumsy and prone to error (and as @thomas pointed out, it can't survive minification).  So I've used a variant of this function on multiple occasions:

```js
function pFunc( ){
    var retOb= {
        name: function(){
            if( typeof this.machinename == 'undefined' ) {
                for( thisObject in window ){
                    if( this === window[thisObject] ){
                            this.machinename = thisObject;
                    }
                }
            }
            return this.machinename;
        },
        makeDiv : function(){
            $(document.body).append( "<div>" + this.name() + " generated this div!</div>" );
        }
    }
    return retOb;
}
```

...effectively creating sub function that walks the dom to find the instance of its parent.

(The "makediv" function is just to give an example of WHY I would want to do this.)

When I did this the first time years ago, I thought I was being terribly clever... but I have NEVER seen anyone else do it or suggest it... so I've grown increasingly concerned that it is bad practice.

1. Is that a horrible idea (and why)?
2. Is it unnecessary (ie, is there a better or more accepted method of having a function be able to identify itself to items it creates)?

Comment: why are you having the function identity itself?

Comment: Why not just write `$(document.body).append( "<div>pFunc generated this div!</div>" );`? Function names are an integral part of your code; there's no reason to try to write your code in such a way that it doesn't depend on the function names.

Comment: The simplest scenario is developer centric: If I'm looking at the dom and want to identify who spawned what, I can use it to have the parent function add its name to the classes of all the divs.

Comment: Because pFunc is instanced... so it isn't always called pFunc.

ie: myOb = pFunc();myOb.makeDiv();

<div>myOb generated this div!</div>

Comment: Down voting without commenting is exceptionally bad form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`arguments.callee.toString().match(/function ([^\(]+)/)[1]);`

This will get you the name from inside the function. Store this as a property and then access it when needed.

Live example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWXVJP

Read more about this technique:

http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript/functions/how-to-get-function-name-from-itself.htm

I'll add that it's very strange that you are trying to do this, and I would consider rethinking the way in which you are doing whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: It should be noted that ES5 Strict Mode will slap you with a `TypeError` if you try this nonsense. `arguments.callee` should be avoided (it should actually be deprecated, but yadda yadda edge-case bugs).

Comment: I actually thought the same when I saw it, the callee was not dependable.  I'm trying it anyway just out of curiousity, but I don't think this method is safer or better (though it is WAY more concise).

Comment: Actually scratch what I said about concise, there isn't a succinct way to do this inside of an instance that I can find, at least nothing that is any better than what I'm already doing.

Comment: What is /function ([^\(]+)/)[1]?

Comment: `arguments.callee.toString` will give you a string printout of the entire function (you can try it yourself). The regex you point out matches just the part after "function" which is the name of the function

Answer (score 0):

this is a bad practice; both of them. first of all, as soon as your app uses namespaces or a minifier, this will blow up.

The name of a function, a property or a variable, is nothing you can rely on; a reference is! If you want a particular function to identify the instances it created, i would reccomend the following structure

```
function Foo(value){
    var me = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
    //process arguments, apply properties and methods
    me.value = value;
    return me;
}

//Foo.prototype...   //works

var obj = Foo("obj1");  //new-keyword has got optional
console.log(obj.value, obj instanceof Foo);     //obj is an instance of Foo
console.log(obj.constructor, obj.constructor === Foo);  //therefore the constructor...

//this starts to lead into a creepy direction; but you requested it
var obj2 = obj.constructor("obj2");
console.log(obj2.value, obj2 instanceof Foo);
console.log(obj2.constructor, obj2.constructor === Foo);
```

Comment: Actually minimizing is a great reason why passing the name is not acceptable.  I should have said that, [facepalm].  However, I'm not clear how my solution would be affected by a minifier?  Also your code returns  ""default" which is not the name, and I can't say I grock what you are trying to show me.  The idea is that obj should know it is called obj

Comment: `I'm not clear how my solution would be affected by a minifier?` take a look at the function-names output by a minifier. How many functions named "e" (for example) do you think are generated? wich one is meant? are you going to register them all in the global namespace? what if your function is not registered under window, but as a property of some library(-namespace)-object?

Comment: `The idea is that obj should know it is called obj` I can't come up with a single idea where you would want/need that, and where it is not grown out the lack of knowing a better solution. `Also your code returns ""default" which is not the name`, yeah, this was a FAIL. I tried to include prototypal inheritance and composition in the example, not providing the constructor. But before I change the code I'd like to know what you're trying to achieve with that? providing a meaningful solution.

Comment: @anyone passing by, changed the code, OhkaBaka is referring to.

Comment: My current use is a js particle generator system. There might be 5 particle emitters active at once, each creating divs in the dom, in generalities it is easy enough to have the emitter track all of its children... impossible not to really, but once they are on the page there is no way for other emitters, functions, or me to know who they belong to without asking each emitter "Hey, is this yours?"... whereas with my solution, the emitter tags each of the divs with its own name.

Comment: Interesting thoughts on the namespace, I'm certainly guilty of not seeing all the possible use cases of my code, but my ego is not such that I think it is likely it would ever happen in this case.  The minifier concern less so... there can only be one e in this scope... if e was replaced with a new e, the function would obviously cease to function anyway, and it wouldn't much matter.

Comment: Possibly more straightforward example:  the function creates divs that have onclick callbacks that iterate a counter in the function that created them.  (There is a tickling in my brain about a better way to do this [and by extension, the previous example as well], but I'm not seeing it straight away)...